# Using DSolveValue to get Analytic Solution to the Helmholtz Equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, boundary-conditions

I am trying to get Mathematica to verify my analytic solution to the following problem:
$$ \Delta u + u = 0 \quad\quad\text{on }\ D=[-3,3]\times[-3,3] $$
$$ u(x,y) = \sin(\frac{\pi x}{6}) \quad\quad\text{on }\ \partial D $$
However, it is telling me "General solution is not available for the given linear pde". Is there an error in the following code?

```
eqn = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + u[x, y] == 0;
bc = {u[-3, y] == -1, u[3, y] == 1, u[x, -3] == Sin[(\[Pi]x)/6], 
   u[x, 3] == Sin[(\[Pi]x)/6]};
sol = DSolveValue[{eqn, bc}, u[x, y], {x, y}] // FullSimplify
```

If there aren't any obvious reasons, can someone explain why Mathematica can't handle this PDE? Further, are there any other Mathematica functions that can be used to find a symbolic solution?

Note, I don't want to find a numerical approximation. Thanks!

EDIT: I also tried breaking this problem up into $4$ separate problems that each solve the PDE, one non-homogeneous BC, and three homogeneous BC. However, since the BCs at the corners aren't zero this didn't exactly give the right solution.

Comment: Maple 2021 fails with it too. `eqn = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + u[x, y] == 0;
bc = {u[-3, y] == -1, u[3, y] == 1, u[x, -3] == Sin[(Pi*x)/6], 
   u[x, 3] == Sin[(Pi*x)/6]};
sol = NDSolve[{eqn, bc}, u[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}];Plot3D[u[x, y] /. sol, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]` works for me in 12.3.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: First negclecting `bc`, Mathematica gives an analytical solution: `U = DSolveValue[{eqn(*,bc*)}, u, {x, y}] // FullSimplify` depending on five parameters .Perhaps it's possible to adapt your boundary conditions in the next step?

Comment: `DSolveValue[eqn, u[x, y], {x, y}]` produces "`DSolve::lpde: General solution is not available for the given linear partial differential equation. Trying to build a special solution.`" and `E^(-x Sqrt[C[
  5]]) (E^(2 x Sqrt[C[5]]) C[1] + C[2]) (C[4] Cos[y Sqrt[1 + C[5]]] + 
   C[3] Sin[y Sqrt[1 + C[5]]])`.

Comment: BTW, `FullSimplify` does nothing in the above.

Comment: `DSolveValue[eqn, u[x, y], {x, y}]` gives a special solution depending on five free parameters!!!

Comment: @joseph If you try to verify your(!) analytical solution,  you might substitude your solution into the `eqn` and `bc`!?!

Comment: Thanks for all the comments I appreciate the help! I did try substituting my solution into eqn and bc to verify that way after seeing @UlrichNeumann's comment, and it worked. Now I'm moreso just curious as to how I would go about getting this to work because if possible, it would save a lot of time in solving future problems.

Comment: I will try to see if I can get the solution with the five parameters and then solve for each of them using my boundary conditions. Thanks again!

Comment: @joseph Could you show the solution you tried to verify?

Comment: The command of Maple 2021 (There was a typo in my previous attempt.) `pdsolve({diff(u(x, y), x, x) + diff(u(x, y), y, y) + u(x, y) = 0, u(-3, y) = 0, u(3, y) = 1, u(x, -3) = sin(Pi*x/6), u(x, 3) = sin(Pi*x/6)}, u(x, y))` answers  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rbb1uj1w1d27svb/pdsolve.pdf?dl=0

Comment: With Greenfunction and some manual effort analytical solution follows to $$\sum _{k=2}^{\text{nn}} \sum _{l=1}^{\text{nn}} \frac{\left(-\left(\left(\pi ^2-36\right) k
   (\cos (\pi  k)+1)\right)\right) (6-6 \cos (\pi  l)) \left(\sin \left(\frac{1}{6} \pi  k
   (x+3)\right) \sin \left(\frac{1}{6} \pi  l (y+3)\right)\right)}{\frac{9}{36} \left(6 \pi 
   \left(k^2-1\right)\right) (\pi  l) \left(-\pi ^2 k^2-\pi ^2 l^2+36\right)}+\sin
   \left(\frac{\pi  x}{6}\right)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am unsure whether the question is still relevant, but found an analytical solution, derived with the help of `Greenfunction`:

First it's necessary to transform the pde `{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + u[x, y] == 0`  to homogenuous boundaryconditions

```
pde=Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + u[x, y] /.u -> Function[{x, y}, Sin[Pi x/6] +v[x, y]] // Collect[#, Sin[__], Simplify] &
```

$$v^{(0,2)}(x,y)+v^{(2,0)}(x,y)+v(x,y)+\left(1-\frac{\pi ^2}{36}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{6}\right)=0
$$

Homogenuous boundarycondition `v[x,y]==0` on the boundary of `rect`

In the next step we try to solve `pde` using `GreenFunction`. That means we are looking for a solution of $$v^{(0,2)}(x,y)+v^{(2,0)}(x,y)+v(x,y)=\delta (x-\xi ) \delta (y-\eta )$$

The documentation shows a similar example.
Unfortunately Mathematica at present is only able to solve the problem in a rectangular region with one corner  `{0,0}` (see [GreenFunction for Helmholtz equation in arbitrary Rectangle region doesn't evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/259556/greenfunction-for-helmholtz-equation-in-arbitrary-rectangle-region-doesnt-evalu))

That's why we have to modify `Greenfunction`
for our purpose:

```
green = Block[{gre, rechteck = rect},
gre = GreenFunction[{Laplacian[v [x , y ], {x , y }] + v [x, y],DirichletCondition[v [x, y] == 0, True]}, v , 
Element[{x, y},TranslationTransform[{ 3, 3}][rechteck]], {\[Xi], \[Eta]}]  ;
Function[{x, y, \[Xi], \[Eta]},gre[x - 3, y - 3, \[Xi] - 3, \[Eta] - 3] //
Evaluate] ]
```

greenfunction `gre[x, y, \[Xi], \[Eta]]:`:

$$-\frac{1}{9} \underset{K[1]=1}{\overset{\infty }{\sum
   }}\underset{K[2]=1}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\frac{\sin \left(\frac{1}{6} \pi  (x-3)
   K[1]\right) \sin \left(\frac{1}{6} \pi  (\xi -3) K[1]\right) \sin \left(\frac{1}{6} \pi 
   (y-3) K[2]\right) \sin \left(\frac{1}{6} \pi  (\eta -3) K[2]\right)}{\frac{1}{36} \pi ^2
   K[1]^2+\frac{1}{36} \pi ^2 K[2]^2-1}$$

`Function[{x,y, \[Xi], \[Eta]},-(1/9) Inactive[Sum][(Sin[1/6 \[Pi] (-3 + x)K[1]] Sin[1/6 \[Pi] (-3 + \[Xi])K[1]] Sin[1/6 \[Pi] (-3 + y) K[2]] Sin[1/6 \[Pi] (-3 + \[Eta]) K[2]])/(-1 + 1/36\[Pi]^2 K[1]^2 + 1/36 \[Pi]^2 K[2]^2), {K[1], 1, \[Infinity]}, {K[2], 1, \[Infinity]}]]`

The analytical solution `u[x,y]` follows to

```
nn=5 ;  
Integrate [green[x,y, \[Xi], \[Eta]] (-(1 - 1/36 \[Pi]^2) Sin[(\[Pi] \[Xi])/6]) /.Infinity -> nn// Activate, Element[{\[Xi], \[Eta]}, rect]] 
Plot3D[%% + Sin[Pi x/6], Element[{x, y}, rect]]
```

[image]

$$\frac{128}{25} \left(1-\frac{\pi ^2}{36}\right) \left(\frac{15 \left(\frac{5 \sin
   \left(\frac{\pi  x}{3}\right)}{5 \pi ^2-36}-\frac{2 \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi 
   x}{3}\right)}{17 \pi ^2-36}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi  y}{6}\right)}{\pi
   ^2}+\left(\frac{25 \sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{3}\right)}{36 \pi ^2-13 \pi ^4}+\frac{10 \sin
   \left(\frac{2 \pi  x}{3}\right)}{\pi ^2 \left(25 \pi ^2-36\right)}\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{\pi  y}{2}\right)+\frac{3 \left(\frac{5 \sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{3}\right)}{29
   \pi ^2-36}-\frac{2 \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  x}{3}\right)}{41 \pi ^2-36}\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{5 \pi  y}{6}\right)}{\pi ^2}\right)$$

The analytical solution agrees very well with the numerical solution

```
numU = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + u[x, y] == 0,DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Sin[(Pi x)/6], True]}, u,Element[{x, y}, rect]]`
Plot3D[numU[x, y], Element[{x, y}, rect]]
```

[image]

Comment: if  the system is underdetermined, we need more BCs, or?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM The system is welldefined with boundary conditions defined on the edge of the rectangle! Why do you expect underdetermined system?

Comment: First, I do not expect underdetermined system. I test the original model using NDsolve, we can find: NDSolveValue::underdet: There are more dependent variables, {u[x,-3],u[x,3],u[x,y],(u^(0,2))[x,y]}, than equations, so the system is underdetermined.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Look at the end of my answer, here you might find a numerical solution

Comment: Thanks! I found it!

Comment: Thanks so much - incredible answer!

Comment: @joseph Hope your solution and my answer are the same ???

Comment: So I orginally solved the problem analytically using superposition since we have a linear PDE (translating the problem to 4 separate problems each dealing with only one non-homogeneous BC). I then I solved these 4 and added them together thinking that would solve the original problem - and it did except for at the corners where it was identically zero. To fix this issue, I added a correction term: $v(x,y) = \frac{\cos(y/\sqrt{2})\sin(x/\sqrt{2})}{\cos(3/\sqrt{2})\sin(3/\sqrt{2})}$ which solves Helmholtz equation and has the correct values I went at the corners.

Comment: Then rather than solving the original problem I solved a new problem where the BC is the original minus the contribution from this correction term

Comment: Its form likes quite different from yours but when I plot it, it looks identical. I also found the same Green's function for the problem which makes me hopeful

Comment: I guess moreso what I was hoping to get out of this thread was how to use Mathematica to verify this work which your answer seems to show quite nicely - for instance I didn't even realize there was a built-in Greenfunction

Comment: @joseph I'm  glad to be able to help a bit.