# GreenFunction for Helmholtz equation in arbitrary Rectangle region doesn't evaluate

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug persists through `V13.0.0` or later**

Here is a basic example found in the documentation of `GreenFunction`:

```
reg = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];
GreenFunction[
   {Laplacian[v[x, y], {x, y}] + v[x, y], 
    DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, True]},
   v, Element[{x, y}, reg], {ξ, η}
]

(* Function[{x, y, ξ, η}, -4 Inactive[Sum][(Sin[π x K[1]] Sin[π ξ K[1]] Sin[π y K[2]] Sin[π η K[2]])/(-1 + π^2 K[1]^2 + π^2 K[2]^2), {K[1], 1, ∞}, {K[2], 1, ∞}]] *)
```

The above evaluates symbolically as expected.

But if I shift the region:

```
reg = Rectangle[{-1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}]
GreenFunction[
   {Laplacian[v[x, y], {x, y}] + v[x, y], 
    DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, True]},
   v, Element[{x, y}, reg], {ξ, η}
]
```

then `GreenFunction` no longer evaluates and returns the input!

What could be the reason ? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I think this is reportable to Support. [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/210289)

Comment: Thank you for your answer: What is the correct way to contact mathematica support? Thanks!

Comment: Send them a message [here](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback).

Comment: This seems to fall under the [tag:bugs] category

Comment: @J. M. Thank you, I'll contact Wolfram!

Comment: The link that @J.M. provided is in Mathematica under the `Help` menu, i.e., `Give Feedback...`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you, good to know.